# bash: expanding function arguments

Tags: git, bash, function, shell

I have an issue with a bash function for a shell script i'm writing. The function is as follows:

```
do_command() {
  if [[ $DRY_RUN ]]; then
    echo $@
  else
    $@
  fi
}
```

Function is simple, if the DRY_RUN flag is set we just print the method otherwise it is executed. This works well for most commands except git tag command that I have tried different versions of like:

```
do_command git tag -a $NEW_VERSION -m '$INPUT_COMMENT'
```

That actually executes the tag command, but give the comment *$INPUT_COMMENT*

I have tried 2 other versions that gives the correct echo output, but doesn't allow me to execute the git tag command.

```
do_command git tag -a $NEW_VERSION -m "$INPUT_COMMENT"
```

and

```
do_command git tag -a $NEW_VERSION -m "\"$INPUT_COMMENT\""
```

Is there some way to make both echo and git command work in this call? Or do I need to parse in the do_command version?

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ would have caught this one without needing to invoke human review.

Comment: (As another aside -- all-uppercase names are conventional for shell builtins and environment variables, but using them for regular, non-exported variables is bad form, as it means you can unintentionally overwrite variables in the other categories).

Comment: Keep in mind that commands like `do_command` will only work with simple commands. No pipes, no `&&`/`||` lists, no I/O redirections, no complex commands: nothing that requires syntax beyond a command name and its arguments.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the feedback, always good with online tools that helps you, updated all variables to lowe case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `"$@"` with quotes to handle arguments with whitespace correctly. If you just write `$@` then the `git` command won't work when `$INPUT_COMMENT` contains whitespace.

```
do_command() {
  if [[ $DRY_RUN ]]; then
    echo "$@"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}
```

Usage:

```
do_command git tag -a $NEW_VERSION -m "$INPUT_COMMENT"
```

Comment: I'd suggest `printf '%q ' "$@"; echo` instead for the DRY_RUN case; that way output visually distinguishes between `"foo bar" baz` and `foo bar baz`.

Comment: I advocate using double quotes around _every_ use of a variable (unless you explicitly want to have the effects occurring with white space in the values), so also use `"$DRY_RUN"` and `"$NEW_VERSION"`.  And if `DRY_RUN` is either `"true"` or `"false"` you can simply write `if "$DRY_RUN"; then`.  Makes it more readable.

Comment: @Alfe, ...well, `[[ ]]` is an exceptional case; `$DRY_RUN` doesn't need to be quoted there because the context implicitly prevents string-splitting and glob expansion. As a general rule, though, you're entirely spot-on.

Comment: @Alfe, (also, I tend to consider using `true` or `false` as values very poor form, as evaluating them as commands means you're *running arbitrary commands*, which is a dangerous habit to get into if you write scripts whose arguments cross privilege boundaries; far, far better to test for empty vs non-empty as done here, or zero vs nonzero, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right concerning security aspects.  But if you are just using your own code and only your own variables, flags, etc., I think readability beats vague security concerns.  But the trouble is that one never knows if a script or a part of it will later be used in a different context.  So if you are concerned with this, you might feel safer with `0`/`1` or empty/nonempty values and tests like `if [ "$flag" = 1 ]; then`.

Comment: @Alfe, I care about "readability", but extend that to having it be easy to understand -- at a read -- the complete set of possible behaviors a piece of code can have when executed. This makes security and correctness concerns also readability concerns -- if code can be made to execute arbitrary commands, _you don't know what it will actually do in all cases just by reading it_.

Comment: @Alfe -- Sloppiness also amplifies the effect of unintentional bugs: If `DRY_RUN` is supposed to be set earlier in your script, but there's a code path where it's uninitialized, then an external value could be inherited through the environment, so suddenly the variable you assumed could only have two possible values has an unbounded set.

Comment: I can only agree (again).  Security concerns suggest to use a less readable way facilitating a comparison rather than a direct call.  All I say is that security and other aspects should be weighed against each other, and the outcome can differ depending on the circumstances.  It was good to think about that topic.